# What is the scope of constructor injected variables?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, dependency-injection

Is there a difference between this

```
$dependency1 = array();
$dependency2 = new SomeObject;

$di = new OtherObject($dependency1, $dependency2);
```

and this?

```
$di = new OtherObject(array(), new SomeObject);
```

In the first example, the $dependency vars are being exposed to the global scope, this is obvious. But what about the second example? Does it create encapsulation?

Is the same true for arguments passed into public methods as well?

I would test it, but I'm not sure how to go about it...

Answer (score 1):

In second case, you won't be seeing those two parameters, unless you know, that `OtherObject`'s constructor assigns them to some public properties.

Answer (score 0):

The first method leaves two references to the parameters in global space. That's about it. Use the first method if there are additional components the need to be injected with the same shared dependencies.